# Small Neuronal Network does not train : wrong Dataset or coding error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

NN- gurus!
I am new both in Tensorflow and the Deep Learning stuff, and i created a small tutorial of full connected NN.

Having input as 2 values,  represending x and y of some points in range of 0...1, i want distinquish... just if points are in the middle. Simple, huh?
Literaly, my inputs and expected data are :

```
inputs = [[0,0],
      [0,0.3],
      [0.3,0],
      [0.3,0.5],
      [0.5,0.3],
      [0.7,0.5],
      [0.5,0.6],
      [0.7,0],
      [0,0.6],
      [0.5,1],
      [0,1],
      [1,1],
      [1, 0.5]]

expected = [[0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1]]
```

**So i expect output[0,1] from those what "is at the border" and [1,0] from the middle.** 
Howewer, taking this as a dataset after 100000 iterations (!) seems to work bad: points at the edge are recognized good, but those from the middle producing output near [0.5,0.5],
 and points what were not in the training set produce even worse result.
I d like to know what causes this error. Is it wrong task setting, network build, parameters, etc?
Or there is wrong usage on TensorFlow itself?
So again here is a complete .py file:

```
    '''
Created on Jan 9, 2018

@author: noob
'''

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# trying to recognice points in the middle as 1,0
print("hello from python")
inputs = [[0,0],
          [0,0.3],
          [0.3,0],
          [0.3,0.5],
          [0.5,0.3],
          [0.7,0.5],
          [0.5,0.6],
          [0.7,0],
          [0,0.6],
          [0.5,1],
          [0,1],
          [1,1],
          [1, 0.5]]

expected = [[0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [1,0],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1],
            [0,1]]


test_inputs = [[0.4,0.1],
          [0.5,0.5],
          [0.9,0.2],
          [0.4,0.6]]

test_expected = [[0,1],
                 [1,0],
                 [0,1],
                 [1,0]]



# ---------- Define Layers ---------------------
in_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,2])

in_to_middle = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,10]))

middle_layer = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

middle_to_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,2]))

out_layer = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

out_expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,2])


middle_layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(in_layer,in_to_middle))

out_layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(middle_layer,middle_to_out))

out_error = (out_expected - out_layer)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(out_error))




train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.8).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

print("starting to train")
for i in range (100000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {
       in_layer : [inputs[i % inputs.__len__()]],
       out_expected : [expected[i % expected.__len__()]]
        })
    if (i%10000 == 0):
        print("step %d" % i)
print("done training")


#print("in: %s out: %s loss: %s"%(curr_in, curr_out, curr_loss))                 

def toColor(out):    
    return 'red' if (out[1] > out[0]) else 'black' #(diff,diff,diff)

def toColor2(out):    
    return 'orange' if (out[1] > out[0]) else 'blue' #(diff,diff,diff)

#for i in range (inputs.__len__()):
 #   plt.plot(inputs[i][0], inputs[i][1], color = toColor(expected[i]),marker='o')
print("----- DATA FROM TRAINING SET ---------") 
for i in range (inputs.__len__()):
    curr_in, curr_out, curr_expected, curr_loss = sess.run([in_layer, out_layer, out_expected, loss],
                                         feed_dict = {
                                        in_layer : [inputs[i]], 
                                        out_expected : [expected[i]]
                                        })
    print("----\nin: %s \nout: %s \nexpected %s \nloss: %s"%(curr_in, curr_out, curr_expected, curr_loss))
    plt.plot(curr_in[0][0], curr_in[0][1], color=toColor(curr_out[0]),marker='o' )

print("----- DATA NOT IN  TRAINING SET ---------") 
for i in range (test_inputs.__len__()):
    curr_in, curr_out, curr_expected, curr_loss = sess.run([in_layer, out_layer, out_expected, loss],
                                         feed_dict = {
                                        in_layer : [test_inputs[i]], 
                                        out_expected : [test_expected[i]]
                                        })
    print("----\nin: %s \nout: %s \nexpected %s \nloss: %s"%(curr_in, curr_out, curr_expected, curr_loss))    


    plt.plot(curr_in[0][0], curr_in[0][1], color=toColor2(curr_out[0]),marker='o' )
plt.axis((0,1,0,1))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your output is binary, so you should round the output of the output layer

```
out_layer = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(...))
```

Secondly, is your loss converging? If it is and you're still getting bad results, try lowering the learning rate (to 0.1, for example) and see what happens.

Comment: expected is binary, but the real one will not achieve it and i guess rounding it will destroy the error calculation. Because for  expected like [0,1] and 
output [0,0.7] the error will be [0, 0.3] what you will not have if you round.
the loss is very disproportional to each point: some points become having NO error at all, some after the training even maximal possible error [1,0] for [0,1]. I can just guess what is fron in the task setting itself

Comment: ahh i found one stuff 
- first, the weights must be initialized as RANDOM (0,1), for example random normals instead of ZEROS, that makes the recognition better.
I ll try other things to do...